# Problema no tamanho do nome do FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

Tenho uma `WebApi` para trabalhar com uma base de Dados do `Firebird 2.5`, utilizei na época o EF, só que hoje está me apresentando o seguinte erro

> "The name 'FK_ARRUMACAO_CHECKLIST_ARRUMACAO_ARRUMACAO_ID' is longer
>   than Firebird's 31 characters limit for object names."

Sei que há limitação na nomeação dos campos `Colunas`, `Tabelas`, `Indices`, etc no firebird, e como é uma base de um sistema legado não tem os mapeamentos corretos das entidades, na base dificilmente vai possuir FK, por algum motivo o EF está gerando automaticamente o nome FK estourando o limite de caracteres, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de setar o nome da ForeignKey pelo EF seja por DataAnnotations ou mesmo FluentApi?

```
[Table("IMPRESSAO_DETALHE")]
public class ImpressaoDetalhe
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_IMP_DET_IMP_ID")]
    [Column("ID_IMPRESSAO")]
    public int ImpressaoId { get; set; }
    [Column("LINHA")]
    public string Linha { get; set; }
    [Column("ORDEM")]
    public int Ordem { get; set; }

    public virtual Impressao Impressao { get; set; }
}
```

Eu consigo dar um nome para o índice

```
[Index("IX_IMP_DET_IMP_ID")]
```

Porém para FK o DataAnnotations não é possível

Answer (score 2):

Quando você cria uma propriedade com um DataAnnotation `ForeignKey` referenciando a sua propriedade de navegação (nesse caso é a propriedade `Impressao)`, o Entity Framework cria o nome da sua `ForeignKey` igual a sua propriedade que possui o DataAnnotation.

```
[Table("IMPRESSAO_DETALHE")]
public class ImpressaoDetalhe
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_IMP_DET_IMP_ID")]
    [ForeignKey("Impressao")]
    public int ImpressaoId { get; set; }

    [Column("LINHA")]
    public string Linha { get; set; }

    [Column("ORDEM")]
    public int Ordem { get; set; }

    public virtual Impressao Impressao { get; set; }
}
```

Nesse caso a sua ForeignKey no banco de dados vai ter o nome `ImpressaoId`, pois é o nome da sua propriedade que está referenciando a propriedade de navegação `Impressao`.